# matching multiple groups only if they are present

Tags: regex

I have the following possible strings:

```
01/08/2019
01/08/2019 Season 2019. 
Season 4. Episode 49 of 134.
Panic Run Season 2. Episode 2 of 12.
```

which I want to breakdown into groups using single regex expression
For instance last string should create 3 matching groups

```
group1: Panic Run
group2:  Season 2.
group3:  Episode 2 of 12.
```

I can have the following regex expression

```
(.+?)(Season.+?\.)(?:.+?)(Episode.+?\.)
```

but it fails the minute of either Episode or Season keyword isn't present

if I put ? at the end (.+?)(Season.+?.)(?:.+?)(Episode.+?.)?
the last group is covered in case it isn't present, however if Season isn't present then the whole expression fails

I want to capture everything in group 1 if the string doesn't start from Season.
if Season is present then capture from Season onwards until . into group 1or2
if Episode is present capture from Episode onwards until . into group 2or3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you might want to design an expression, somewhat similar to:

```
(?i)^(\d+\/\d+\/\d+)?(.*?)(\bSeason\s+\d+)?\.?\s*(Episode.+\d)?\.?$
```

not sure though.

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/KiJjNr/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/KiJjNr/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

Comment: awesome! thanks!  i simplified it to my needs, the ? after each group wasn't working for some reason as I didn't put beginning and end of the string definition `^(.*?)\s(Season.+?)?\.?\s*(Episode.+?)?\.$`